# \part and tocloft

Tags: table-of-contents, hyperref, tocloft, parts

The following code was provided by Martin Scharrer in reply to a post in May 10.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[british]{babel}
\usepackage[titles]{tocloft}

\usepackage{tocloft}

\newlength\mylenprt
\newlength\mylenchp
\newlength\mylenapp

\renewcommand\cftpartpresnum{\partname~}
\renewcommand\cftchappresnum{\chaptername~}
\renewcommand\cftchapaftersnum{.}

\settowidth\mylenprt{\cftpartfont\cftpartpresnum\cftpartaftersnum}
\settowidth\mylenchp{\cftchapfont\cftchappresnum\cftchapaftersnum}
\settowidth\mylenapp{\cftchapfont\appendixname~\cftchapaftersnum}
\addtolength\mylenprt{\cftpartnumwidth}
\addtolength\mylenchp{\cftchapnumwidth}
\addtolength\mylenapp{\cftchapnumwidth}

\setlength\cftpartnumwidth{\mylenprt}
\setlength\cftchapnumwidth{\mylenchp}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{colorlinks=true}


\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\mainmatter

\part{First Part}
\chapter{First Chapter}

\appendix
\addtocontents{toc}{% NB!!! must be inside the first \include
    \protect\renewcommand\protect\cftchappresnum{\appendixname~}%
    \protect\setlength{\cftchapnumwidth}{\mylenapp}}%

\chapter{First Appendix}

\end{document}
```

To experiment with hyperlinks, I have added the following to the above.

```
\usepackage{hyperref} 

\hypersetup{colorlinks=true}
```

After running LaTeX, a table of contents is created with `Part I. First Part` as the title of the part above.  However, the word `Part`, unlike the rest, does not have hyperlink.  I wonder how the hyperlink can be extended to include the word `Part`.

Answer (score 9):

In this case, instead of using `tocloft` to change the part entries (these entries and `tocloft` don't cooperate well), I'd rather redefine the `\@part` command (as implemented in `book.cls`):

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[british]{babel}
\usepackage[titles]{tocloft}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{colorlinks=true}

\makeatletter
\def\@part[#1]#2{%
    \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >-2\relax
      \refstepcounter{part}%
      \addcontentsline{toc}{part}{\partname~\thepart\hspace{1em}#1}%
    \else
      \addcontentsline{toc}{part}{#1}%
    \fi
    \markboth{}{}%
    {\centering
     \interlinepenalty \@M
     \normalfont
     \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >-2\relax
       \huge\bfseries \partname\nobreakspace\thepart
       \par
       \vskip 20\p@
     \fi
     \Huge \bfseries #2\par}%
    \@endpart}
\makeatother

\newlength\mylenchp
\newlength\mylenapp

\renewcommand\cftchappresnum{\chaptername~}
\renewcommand\cftchapaftersnum{.}

\settowidth\mylenchp{\cftchapfont\cftchappresnum\cftchapaftersnum}
\settowidth\mylenapp{\cftchapfont\appendixname~\cftchapaftersnum}
\addtolength\mylenchp{\cftchapnumwidth}
\addtolength\mylenapp{\cftchapnumwidth}

\setlength\cftchapnumwidth{\mylenchp}

\begin{document}

\frontmatter
\tableofcontents
\mainmatter

\part{First Part}
\chapter{First Chapter}

\appendix
\addtocontents{toc}{% NB!!! must be inside the first \include
    \protect\renewcommand\protect\cftchappresnum{\appendixname~}%
    \protect\setlength{\cftchapnumwidth}{\mylenapp}}%

\chapter{First Appendix}

\end{document}
```

[image]